# How can i solve this error "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CtnController::show(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, laravel-blade, laravel-views

I have reviewed similar questions but none of the solutions worked for me. I have show view that fetches data from the db which I want to display. I believe I have the right code for my show function on my CtnController but I keep getting this frustrating error. Ctn in this case is a type of form I'm trying to create.

This is my controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Ctn;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class CtnController extends Controller
{
           /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
        /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $ctns = Ctn::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);
        return view('/ctn.index')->with('ctns', $ctns);
    }

    public function create(){
    return view('/ctn.create'); 
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $validatedData = $request -> validate([
            'bol' => 'required',
            'carrier' => 'required',
             'address' => 'required',
             'etd' => 'required',
             'eta' => 'required',
             'portload' => 'required',
             'portdischarge' => 'required',

        ]);

        $ctn = new Ctn;
        $ctn->bill_landing = request('bol');
        $ctn->carrier = request('carrier');
        $ctn->address = request('address');
        $ctn->eta = request('eta');
        $ctn->etd = request('etd');
        $ctn->incoterm = request('incoterm');
        $ctn->forwarder = request('forwarder');
        $ctn->ctnref = request('ctnref');
        $ctn->portloading = request('portload');
        $ctn->portdischarge = request('portdischarge');
        $ctn->quantity = request('quantity');
        $ctn->origin_goods = request('origin');
        $ctn->cost_goods = request('cost');
        $ctn->currency = request('currency');
        $ctn->package_type = request('package');

        $ctn->save();
        return redirect('/ctn')->with('success', 'CTN created');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {

        $ctn = Ctn::find($id);
        return view('/ctn.show', compact('ctn'));
    }
}
```

Below is my show route on web.php file

```
Route::get('/ctn/show', 'CtnController@show')->name('show');
```

The show form is just a HTML form.

Comment: Please scroll all the way down to see the show function.

Answer (score 1):

Your `show()` method excepts an `$id`, however, you've not specified the value in your route. Change your route definition so that is can accept the `id`:

```
Route::get('/ctn/show/{id}', 'CtnController@show')->name('show');
```

This will assume that you're using a url like:

```
http://example.com/ctn/show/1
```

For more information you can view the [Route Parameters documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: I have tried adding the id on show route but then I get an error 404 not found

Comment: @ItsCharlie4real Can you give an example of the url you're using?

Answer (score 0):

The `$id` argument of your `show` method expects an implicit binding from the route parameters, but your routes does not know any `id` parameter, therefore it can't be bound to your method.